# Invalid signature when calling ghost admin api

Tags: java, jwt, ghost-blog

I'm trying to call Ghost's admin API to create posts. I generate the JWT token in JAVA using [java-jwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.8.1).

I have a local ghost boot on which I generated a private key. The JSON is sent to the ghost using Postman.

The request

```
GET /ghost/api/v2/admin/posts/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2368
Authorization: Ghost eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVjZWZjOWRlMDhlZTFjMzkxMDBiZjI0OCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIvdjIvYWRtaW4vIiwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aDAiLCJleHAiOjE1NjM3MjcyMTgsImlhdCI6MTU2MzcyNjkxOH0.pLmyGRih22djFAJeeoKtXLYdBHcJki3J1qOL3nV-jKY
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 38e2357f-8b71-466c-9876-7ff57d25b99a
```

The token is valid on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#encoded-jwt) and the signature indicating the secret.

The token is generated with the fields indicated in the [ghost documentation](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v2/admin/#token-authentication).

```java
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(keyBytes);
            Map<String, Object> headerClaims = new HashMap<>();
            headerClaims.put("typ", "JWT");
            headerClaims.put("alg", "HS256");
            headerClaims.put("kid", keyId);


            token = JWT.create()
                    .withHeader(headerClaims)
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .withIssuedAt(new DateTime().toDate())
                    .withExpiresAt(new DateTime().plusMinutes(5).toDate())
                    .withAudience("/v2/admin/")
                    .sign(algorithm);
```

Ghost should send me an HTTP 201 but I get a 401.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid token: invalid signature",
            "context": null,
            "type": "UnauthorizedError",
            "details": null,
            "property": null,
            "help": null,
            "code": "INVALID_JWT",
            "id": "0ce33230-b927-11e9-a560-0b2bc6ae64e3"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem seems to be the admin key since with the key indicated in the code, the token is valid on jwt.io.

Ghost generate : 5cefc9de08ee1c39100bf248:4d8b914f80cbd5297793bb6c8be044a6e7266eb7f08ac90b9c390dd27735a193

I took only the right one after ':' to valued my variable 'keyBytes'

```java
byte[] keyBytes = "4d8b914f80cbd5297793bb6c8be044a6e7266eb7f08ac90b9c390dd27735a193".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Key verification :

```java
String token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVjZWZjOWRlMDhlZTFjMzkxMDBiZjI0OCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIvdjIvYWRtaW4vIiwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aDAiLCJleHAiOjE1NjM3MjcyMTgsImlhdCI6MTU2MzcyNjkxOH0.pLmyGRih22djFAJeeoKtXLYdBHcJki3J1qOL3nV-jKY";
        byte[] keyBytes = "4d8b914f80cbd5297793bb6c8be044a6e7266eb7f08ac90b9c390dd27735a193".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        try {
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(keyBytes);
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception){
            //Invalid signature/claims
        }
```

Any ideas on the error ?

Edit : Found the problem, the secret must be decote from HEX.

```java
byte[] keyBytes = "4d8b914f80cbd5297793bb6c8be044a6e7266eb7f08ac90b9c390dd27735a193".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Must be replace by

```java
byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex("4d8b914f80cbd5297793bb6c8be044a6e7266eb7f08ac90b9c390dd27735a193");
```

Comment: Could you please show us your key verification logic too?

Comment: I edited by adding key verification logic (done in Junit Test)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to authenticate into ghost API v3 using my admin token. I've checked your code sample and it look very similar to mine. I've took yours and I still get 404 when trying to post create webhooks. I did not try the key verification, my code look like this: https://gist.github.com/dba81c41ac913b0daa218cfb0e4a13f7 do you have any thought ?

Comment: Hi, I see that you are creating the claims map for the header, but you forget to put them when you create the JWT token. From memory it's mandatory for ghost !