# How to sign a JWT in Java to authenticate into ghost API v3

Tags: java, api, jwt, auth0, ghost-blog

I would like to [create a webook using Ghost API v3 admin API](https://ghost.org/docs/admin-api/#webhooks)

It is written that you MUST a JWT token [in the authentication part of their documentation](https://ghost.org/docs/admin-api/#token-authentication)

My server is in Java, and this is my snippet:

```java
public GhostBlogAdminApiService createAdminService(GhostBlog blog) throws DecoderException {
    String adminApiKeId = blog.getAdminApiKey().split(":")[0];
    String adminApiKeySecret = blog.getAdminApiKey().split(":")[1];
    byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(adminApiKeySecret.toCharArray());
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(keyBytes);
    Map<String, Object> headerClaims = new HashMap<>();
    headerClaims.put("typ", "JWT");
    headerClaims.put("alg", "HS256");
    headerClaims.put("kid", adminApiKeId);

    Date now = new Date();
    Date in5min = DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(), 5);


    String token = JWT.create()
            .withHeader(headerClaims)
            .withIssuer("auth0")
            .withIssuedAt(now)
            .withExpiresAt(in5min)
            .withAudience("/v3/admin/")
            .sign(algorithm);

    try {
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .withIssuer("auth0")
                .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
        DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        System.out.println(jwt.toString());
    } catch (JWTVerificationException exception){
        //Invalid signature/claims
    }
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(blog.getUrl() + "/ghost/api/v3/admin/")
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create());
    httpClient.interceptors().clear();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
    httpClient.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Headers headers = request.headers().newBuilder().add("Authorization", "Ghost " + token).build();
        request = request.newBuilder().headers(headers).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(GhostBlogAdminApiService.class);
}
```

> I've helped my self with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398091/invalid-signature-when-calling-ghost-admin-api)

Using the token I signed, I keep having 404 when I try to create a `webhooks`.

I've tested the insecure `admin/site` endpoint and it works since it is [without authentication](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/main/core/server/api/v3/site.js#L9).

I multiple checked the endpoint called and there's no mistake.

- Why do I have 404 and the person [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398091/invalid-signature-when-calling-ghost-admin-api) is having 401?
- How did I fail?